# bootstrap class .has-error is not applied properly

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i have a simple form for feedback and doing form-validation from angularJs
however i'm using bootstrap has-error class on name filed and comments field
but it is only applied on name field 
i looked to my code many times and could`nt find any difference between these fields code 
as the file is part of a project and needs some dependencies ill provide a pic of code and pic of result hope that will be sufficient to receive help..
thank u in advance

here is another problem .. i can`t upload pics as files on my pc . i tried to click on images tool here but it seems asking for a url for the image and i only have them locally

any help please?

but for now this is the code :
name field:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': commentsForm.name.$error.required && !commentsForm.name.$pristine}">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label" for="name">Your Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="comments.name" required/>
                                <span class=" help-block" ng-show="commentsForm.name.$error.required && !commentsForm.name.$pristine">Your name?</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

comments field:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': commentsForm.commetns.$error.required && !commentsForm.comments.$pristine}">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label" for="name">Comments</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <textarea class="form-control has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error': commentsForm.comments.$error.required && !commentsForm.comments.$pristine}"
                                id="comments" name="comments" rows="5" placeholder="Your comments" ng-model="comments.comments" required></textarea>
                                <span class=" help-block" ng-show="commentsForm.comments.$error.required && !commentsForm.comments.$pristine">Your comments?</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: you spelt 'comments' incorrectly here: commentsForm.commetns

Comment: How can i accept your editing suggestion for my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be

`ng-class="{'has-error': commentsForm.comments.$error.required && !commentsForm.comments.$pristine}"`

instead of

`ng-class="{'has-error': commentsForm.commetns.$error.required && !commentsForm.comments.$pristine}"`